# Navigation issue with storyboard in iOS 7

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, navigation

when I try to push a segue on Back button click of a navigation Controller then it show view distorted.

**It works fine for iOS 8**

**Shows me log**
`nested push animation can result in corrupted navigation bar`
& `Finishing up a navigation transition in an unexpected state. Navigation Bar subview tree might get corrupted`

My code is as follow:

```
    -(void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {

        if ([self.navigationController.viewControllers indexOfObject:self]==NSNotFound) {
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"PaymentToMyads" sender:nil]; 
 //push a new view on back button
        }
        [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    }
```

Comment: Can I ask you what is purpose of your code? Why you want to perform segue when your controller is disappearing?

Comment: @LiborZapletal, it will push to new view in storyboard file.

Comment: why wanting to push new view when user is expecting to get back?

Comment: Also your condition will always be true, as when this method is called, that view controller `must` be in that array.

Comment: @Losiowaty, My controller may not be in the array

Comment: @SyedAliSalman, even if I try to pop to root view then also it creates problem

Comment: How? The only reason for it to not be on the stack of `navigationController.viewControllers` while `viewWillDisappear` is fired is when you didn't push it to nvaigation controller.

Comment: @Losiowaty, I try to push a new view when back button press,that's it & it works fine in iOS 8

Comment: try to print navigation controller 's all view controllers and do some R&D on   it than you can easily understood Because in -viewWillDisappear method called than your self goes from stack and than also you push on that that's y.

Comment: because `viewWillAppear` method does not take time to remove self from navigation stack.

Comment: @JAYRAPARKA, Thanks for your answer! how to call method on default back button?

Comment: i think you have to custom your navigation bar or you can use `didMoveToParentViewController` method but not sure about this method..

Answer (score 0):

As for your main problem - `viewWillDisappear:` is too late to segue to another view controller, as this essentially tells you that this transition has already begun. If you want to decide to which controller to go, you have to do it "earlier", for example in a button handler.

Also, as mentioned in comments, it would be considered back practice to redirect user to different view controller on back button, than the one from which they came.

If the 'new view' that you want to push is essentialy the one from which your user came, then there is no need to do it manually. The system does it for you.

Comment: if I try to poptoRootview then also it creates problem,why?

Comment: @Losiowaty said simply you can not navigate from viewWillDisappear
you have to navigate from button handler action.